# Resource does not have neither a source nor a target path. Impossible to add it to the bundle

Tags: drools, kie

I am trying to read `.xlsx` file with rules using `kie api 6`.
However I get this exception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Resource does not have neither a source nor a target path. Impossible to add it to the bundle. P
lease set either the source or target name of the resource before adding it.null
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieFileSystemImpl.write(KieFileSystemImpl.java:83)
        at com.project.watch.validator.RuleValidator.isValidRuleKieNew(RuleValidator.java:71)
        at com.project.watch.validator.RuleValidator.isValidRule(RuleValidator.java:37)
        at com.project.watch.core.WatchDir$ValidateFileRunnable.run(WatchDir.java:177)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:
178)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The code looks like this

```
try { 
        KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
        KieFileSystem kfs = ks.newKieFileSystem();
        kfs.write(ks.getResources().newInputStreamResource(Files.newInputStream(p, StandardOpenOption.READ)));
        KieBuilder kb = ks.newKieBuilder(kfs);
        if (kb.getResults().getMessages(Level.ERROR).size() != 0) {
            logger.lifecycle("Invalid file: {}.", kb.getResults().getMessages());
            return false;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.lifecycle("UNEXPECTED ERROR DURING VALIDATION -------------- ", e);
        return false;
    }
    logger.lifecycle("Valid file: {}.", p);
    return true;
}
```

It fails on `kfs.write` by the way.

I also checked the path to file by displaying it in console

```
Attempt to process rule file: D:\PROJECT_FOLDER\project\src\testInteg\resources\rules\rule.xlsx
```

and it is a correct path. 
What's the problem? I am using `6.3 Final` version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend this mantra, assuming your `String p` contains the path name as shown:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream( p );
kfs.write( "src/main/resources/rule.xslx",
           kieServices.getResources().newInputStreamResource( fis ) );
```

There are some other forms for `write` to the `KieFileSystem`, but I find that this is easy to use. You may derive the `rule.xslx` from `p`, using Java's API for path names.

Comment: Indeed. I solved it like this. But what's the purpose of base `write` in that case?

Comment: A Resource may have a path name associated with it - then the plain `write( Resource resource)` should be sufficient. (Admittedly, I've never tried to fathom this one out, and the documentation is, ahem, is, now where is it, ahem...)